# Android Manage comportment of my webview like in chrome (cross domain trouble)

Tags: android, google-chrome, webview, cross-domain

After many hours of research and tries I am asking help of the community.

First, sorry for my english I am not fluent, so you will find some mistakes.

I have trouble to get the same comportment on my in-app webview and chrome browser. I am thinking about cross domain trouble not well manage in my web view ...

That is the scenario :

I have different environment (Integration, preproduction, production).
I have a web address to sign up for my app. This is managed buy a web-application (not manage by myself).

The webapp has a javascript that sends the signup request to a server. Depending of the environment the webapp page and the server are not on the same domain.

When I am in the integration environment, the webapp is in the same domain as the server.
When I am in the others environments, the webapp is not int the same domain as the server.

When I try to sign up using chrome browser, there is no problem at all and I can sign up in every environment.

When I am using my webview, depending of my environment I m not able to sign up.

I load a local file in my webview. This local html file contains an iframe which has its src tag depending of the environment.
If the src and the server are in the same domain every thing goes right. 
If not, there is trouble.

The trouble is not coming from the server since I can sign up in every environment in Chrome.
So, I am wondering how I can manage my webview to have the same comportment as chrome and got the sign-up working in every environment.

I try to directly load the url of the webapp in myWebView.load(url) but it changed nothing.

Here is my code :

```
package com.something.fr;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleWebviewActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final String TAG = SimpleWebviewActivity.class.getName();

public static final String URL_KEY = "URL_KEY";

private static final String CODE_KEY = "code";
private static final String OPENING_SUCCESSFUL = "OpeningSuccessful";

private ProgressBar mPbar;
private WebView mWv;

private String mUrl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(b != null) {
        mUrl = b.getString(URL_KEY);
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.web_register_activity_layout);
    mPbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.web_register_progress_bar);
    mWv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_register_webview);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();


    WebSettings settings = mWv.getSettings();
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    settings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWv.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            mPbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            mPbar.setProgress(progress);

            if(progress == 100)
                mPbar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        }

    });

    mWv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {



        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
        {
            // Handle the error
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            return false;
        }

    });

    mWv.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "AndroidDelegate");

    if (mUrl != null && !mUrl.isEmpty()) {
         mWv.loadUrl(mUrl);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_url_to_load, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void handlePostMessage(String jsonMsg) {
        JSONObject postMsgJSON = null;
        try {
             postMsgJSON = new JSONObject(jsonMsg);
             String code = postMsgJSON.getString(CODE_KEY);
             Log.d(TAG, "create account response " + code);
             if (code.contentEquals(OPENING_SUCCESSFUL)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"error parsing json from postmessage : " + jsonMsg);
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        }
    }
}
}
```

here is the logs have got from the webconsole :

```
10-08 21:07:06.975: E/Web Console(10259): XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.name_of_the_server_domain.fr/services/compte/ouvrir. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.:1
10-08 21:07:07.020: W/Web Console(10259): Error for [create]@[https://www.name_of_the_server_domain.fr/services/compte/ouvrir] response : {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}:9
```

I hope you understand my problem, and hope that you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english too.

Try add this to ignore SSL errors

```
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    handler.proceed(); // Ignore SSL certificate errors
}
```

to `new WebViewClient()`

It's better if you give some code of html page, witch used `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try this solution. I cannot provide any code from the html page because I don't manage it. It is done by another team.

Comment: Malheureusement ca ne fonctionne pas non plus